# Using Gatlin load testing, how do requests get classified as "KO?"

Tags: load-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

I am using https://gatling.io for load testing an application.  I really appreciate the default reporting from the tool.  After searching the documentation, it's not clear to me how particular requests get classified as "KO."  (or not ok)

We are currently using all the default settings from Gatlin.

We suspect that requests need to respond under 10 seconds from inspection of gatling.conf.

Is this assumption correct?

Comment: For context, these are the reports we're using:
https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/reports/

Answer (score 0):

Anything that fails a `check()` will be a KO

Even if you haven't added a check yourself Gatling checks for an http 2xx or 3xx response by default

https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/http/http_check/

If you're seeing KO's and haven't added any checks it's likely you're getting some 4xx or 5xx responses